# How can I reduce beam intensity without significantly reducing light brightness?

Tags: lighting, unreal

I picked up Unreal 5.0 last week and don't what question to ask the oracle Google to help me fix the problem.

This is what I have. (ImgA)
[image: ImgA]

This is the look I am trying to get. (ImgB)
[image: ImgB]

I started with the basic level layout for my project in ImgA. I want to get the lighting look in ImgB with is from the DMX starter project. What do I need to change or add to my project to get the look I want?